# If-then-else statement doesn't work

Tags: java

I have a main class, what looks like this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Mobil one = new Mobil ("xxxxxx", "yyyyyy", 00000001, true);
        Mobil two = new Mobil ("yyyyyy", "xxxxxx", 10245624, false);

        one.touchcontrol();
        two.touchcontrol();
        }
}
```

And I have this Mobil class:

```
class Mobil {
    String type;
    String manufactureat;
    int modellnumber;
    boolean touchtype;

public Mobil (String manufacturer, String inittype, int number, boolean touch) {
        manufacturer = manufactureat;
        inittype = type;
        number = modellnumber;
        touch = touchtype;
}
public void touchcontrol() {
    if (touchtype == false) 
    {
        System.out.println("This model, has not got Touchscreen!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This model, has Touchscreen!");
    }
}
```

But when I run the program and invoke the `one.touchcontrol();` and `two.touchcontrol();` it shows that no model has got Touchscreen. I don't know what I missed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to swap the variable assignments in the constructor.

```
manufactureat = manufacturer;
type = inittype;
modellnumber = number;
touchtype = touch;
```

In variable assignments in Java (and in pretty much all other languages), the left hand will retrieve the value of the right hand.

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Language Basics - Assignment operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: It might help to distinguish between instance and local variables by using this.x for instance variables or making all instance variables end in _

Comment: @Mark I'd prefer `this` over prefixing/suffixing the name. But that would only confuse the OP at that point. Let him to get used to the language basics first :)

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly assigning values to variables in your constructor...

```
public Mobil (String manufacturer, String inittype, int number, boolean touch) {
        manufacturer = manufactureat; // should be  manufactureat = manufacturer;
        inittype = type;               //same problem
        number = modellnumber;         // same here
        touch = touchtype;               // and here
}
```